# Projectile shotgun in unity: inconsistent spread

Tags: unity-game-engine, transform, velocity, projectile, shotgun

I am trying to make a shooter with a shotgun that is projectile based. However, at certain angles the spread changes from what it should be, im guessing due to the variation in transform. Forward. Is there anyway to fix these seemingly random offsets? `void ElementWeapons(int selection, int alternate)
{
float[] sgxoffsets = new float[8] {-0.025f,.025f,.025f,-.025f,.0175f,-.0175f,-.0175f,.0175f};
float[] sgyoffsets = new float[8] {-0.025f,-.025f,.025f,.025f,-.0175f,-.0175f, .0175f, .0175f };
float[] sgzoffsets = new float[8] { -0.025f, .025f, .025f, -.025f, .0175f, -.0175f, -.0175f, .0175f };
WeaponSwap WepSwap = transform.GetComponent();

```
    switch (selection)
    {
        case 0: //Iron Shotugn Ferrous Fieldpiece
            switch (alternate) {
                case 0:
                    fireRate = 70;
                    if (firing == true)
                    {
                        ttf = Time.time + (1 / (fireRate / 60));
                        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                        {
                            toffset = new Vector3(sgxoffsets[i], sgyoffsets[i], sgzoffsets[i]);
                            var Vial = Instantiate(vial, transform.position, Cam.transform.rotation);
                            Vial.velocity = (90*(transform.forward +toffset));
                            
                            Vial.GetComponent<VialBehavior>().vialElement = EleManager.instance.currentElement;
                            Vial.GetComponent<VialBehavior>().dmg = 2f;
                           
                        }`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Experimenting with Chuck's link, I looked at different options and found `transform.TransformVector`, which created a constant spread see here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    toffset = new Vector3(sgxoffsets[i], sgyoffsets[i], sgzoffsets[i]);
    var Vial = Instantiate(vial, transform.position, Cam.transform.rotation);
    Vial.velocity = (90*(transform.forward + transform.TransformVector(toffset)));
    Vial.GetComponent<VialBehavior>().vialElement = EleManager.instance.currentElement;
    Vial.GetComponent<VialBehavior>().dmg = 2f;
}
```

Comment: ayyy glad you got it <3

Answer (score 0):

I think you're defining the spread in local coordinates but then you're using that with transform.forward which is in world coordinates.

Consider using transform.TransformPoint on the toffset before adding it to transform.forward

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformPoint.html

Comment: I instead used transfrom.TransformVector(toffset) while experimenting with these options and it works wonderfully now. thanks for the introduction to these incredible methods!!